# Неоднородное нелинейное диф. уравнение первого порядка

Tags: математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дано уравнение выше. Как я понял, это должно быть уравнением Бернулли(поскольку во всех других задачах разного варианта ИДЗ последнее зачастую решается как Бернулли).

P.S. Штриха над игриками не было, я просто предположил, что он должен быть там(хотя я пробовал менять добавлять его к другим игрекам, чтобы проверить результат, но различные онлайн калькуляторы выдавали какую-то херню). Препод не отвечает. Проверял на то, что оно могло быть в полных дифф. и проч.

В итоге пришёл к следующему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал, может и не Бернулли это и попробовал замену `y = uv`, но получается всякая дичь(уже сам не знаю что писать).

Прошу помощи.

Comment: Данный ресурс не является помощником по решениям математических уравнений

Comment: Он не ориентирован на это, но это не значит, что я не могу задавать подобные вопросы и просить помощи, ибо встречал подобные. Если не трудно — посоветуйте какой-то нормальный мат. форум.

Comment: [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Так-то, [по правилам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) не можете задавать подобные вопросы. Но согласен, иногда проскакивают

Comment: @InDevX, сообщество не против математических вопросов https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8684/235436.

Comment: @КириллМалышев во-первых, я не говорил что сообщество против, во-вторых, выше я кинул страницу - там до сих пор нет ничего о математике, значит и задавать не стоит, имхо

Comment: @КириллМалышев я изменил название вашего вопроса. Это нелинейное дифференциальное уравнение.

Comment: WolframAlpha в помощь

Comment: WolframAlpha тоже выдает фигню всякую(+ мне надо с развернутым решением, или хотя бы шаги, чтобы я понимаю как решать такие уравнения). @PakUula был прав, надо решить относительно `x`, а не относительно `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше уравнение станет уравнением Бернулли, если его решать как `x(y)`: `dx/dy = xy + x^2y^3`.

Его решение `x = 1/(2 - y^2)`

Обратный переход к `y(x)`: `y = sqrt(2 - 1/x)`

Comment: @LeonardoDiPierro я рад, что вы успешно решили это уравнение :) Да, полный набор решений, конечно, включает параметр `C`, который делает обратную функцию невыразимой )

Comment: Но такой ответ(без C) тоже приемлем ведь, насколько я понял? Просто во всех диффурах C я сохранял, а тут не сохранил чисто из-за сентиментальности, ибо с ней получается уродливое выражение.